# context sensitive lexing & parsing

Tags: antlr4

I have a set of files to parse that has this weird contents. Each line contains the following data(removing all the other contents of no relevance here):

**DATA < Alphabetic data> < numeric data>< Period as terminator>**

and then we could have text which may be as follows:

**TEXT < Alphanumeric data + puntuation (including period)>**

So I am having problem in parsing the DATA line as the numeric data can be of any of the following type:

99.9

99.

.9

Especially to parse data like:

DATA ANACRON99..

The first dot at the end is the decimal point and second is the terminator

A sample of the grammar I tried, copying just the relevant portion is as follows:

```
file: lines+ EOF
;

lines: data_line
     | text_line
;


text_line: TEXT TEXTUALDATA
;

data_line: DATA sensordata
;

sensordata: DATA FLOATVALUE PERIOD
;

TEXT:'TEXT';
DATA: 'DATA' ->mode(SENSORMODE);
TEXTUALDATA: (.)*?
;

mode SENSORMODE;
FLOATVALUE: ([0-9])*('.')([0-9])*
;
WS:[ \t]->skip
;
WS2:[\r\n]
;
PERIOD:'.' ->mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
;
```

This detects the first period as part of floatdata, but completely ignores the second and complains it was expecting PERIOD but found EOF. What could be a way to solve this please. Is there any way to look ahead and at the same time keep track of the last token detected?

Thanks!!

Comment: Both of what GRosenberg & CoronA suggested when used together helped solve this, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`FLOATVALUE` can match a single period and it is listed before `PERIOD`.  So, the lexer is matching two `FLOATVALUE`s in series.

To avoid the ambiguity, change `FLOATVALUE` to:

```
FLOATVALUE: ([0-9])+('.')([0-9])+
          | ([0-9])+('.')
          | ('.')([0-9])+
          ;
```

Answer (score 0):

To avoid that `FLOATVALUE` matches your `PERIOD` you can switch the sequence of your lexer definitions.

```
mode SENSORMODE;
PERIOD:'.' ->mode(DEFAULT_MODE)
;
FLOATVALUE: ([0-9])*('.')([0-9])*
;
WS:[ \t]->skip
;
WS2:[\r\n]
;
```

ANTLR always returns the token type of the longest matching lexer rule and in case of same-length matches it returns the first type. The modified grammar moves `PERIOD` to the first position.